# Java boolean method needs extra return statement?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, primes, return

I am starting with java and while I was writing a way to identify whether a number was prime I wrote a method like this

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n){

    int x = 2;

    while (((n % x) != 0) && (n > x)){
        x = x + 1;
    }

    if(((n % x) == 0) && (n == x)){     
        return !Prime;
    }
    else if(((n % x) == 0) && (n > x)){
        return Prime;
    }
    else {
        return Prime;
    }
}
```

What I couldn't figure out was the necessity of the last else statement. If I do not put it, I get an error message. However I don't think it is necessary since all possibilities are covered by the previous loops, with their respecting return statements. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What you're missing is that while *you* know the rules of number theory, the compiler does not. As far as it knows, there is some case which is not covered, and therefore there must be a return to "cover" that case.

Comment: Skip the last `else` statement and simply return `PrimeOrNot` at the end of the method.  I'm old school and prefer one entry and one exit from all methods. Instead of retuning in the middle of the method, I would simple create a local variable called something like `isPrime`, set to false and simply change it when it need to be true and have one return statement at the end of the method...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: No need for `else` when you `return` -- you can remove two of them here

Comment: @xagyg The error message is : error: missing return statement.

Comment: @MadProgrammer that seems like a safer approach. Thanks

Comment: That is not surprising. As @BheshGurung says in his answer, the conditions are evaluated _at run time_. In order for a method to be considered valid by the compiler, it must return in _all_ its code paths. And there was one code path which was not covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the else. What you are being told by the compiler is the method must return SOMETHING. Your last `else` block could replaced by this:

`return PrimeOrNot;`

In fact, your method could look like this:

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n){
    int x = 2;
    while (((n % x) != 0) && (n > x)){
        x = x + 1;
    }
    if(((n % x) == 0) && (n == x)){     
        return !(PrimeOrNot);
    }
    return (PrimeOrNot);
}
```

In any case your **very last** statement block **cannot** be an `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

The method has a return type of boolean.

The compiler is scared by the possibility in which none of the 'if' cases are met. In this situation, the method know what to return. This method needs to return something, so just give it a 'return true' before the method ends. It won't ever be read, but it will make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expressions within the if/else-if are only evaluated at runtime. Normally, the compiler wouldn't know what the result would be, because they are not evaluated at compile-time. Only, situation when the compiler can figure what the result of the expression would be is when it's some compile-time constant (like `if(true) {`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n){
    boolean PrimeOrNot = false;
    int x = 2;

    while (((n % x) != 0) && (n > x)){
        x = x + 1;
    }

    if(((n % x) == 0) && (n == x)){     
        return !(PrimeOrNot);
    }
    else if(((n % x) == 0) && (n > x)){
        return (PrimeOrNot);
    }

    return PrimeOrNot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only checks to see if there are valid return paths from your method.  The compiler isn't "smart" enough to inspect the conditional statements and determine whether the conditions can be logically met -- the compiler simply checks to make sure that some value is returned to respect the contract of the method declaration.

Some would argue that the following is a cleaner structure for the method (but I think it is just a matter of taste):

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n){
    int x = 2;
    while (((n % x) != 0) && (n > x)){
        x = x + 1;
    }

    if(((n % x) == 0) && (n == x)){     
        return !(PrimeOrNot);
    }

    return (PrimeOrNot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method which returns a value will be compilable if it returns a value in *all its possible code paths*.

Imagine for a moment that you're the compiler. You see this code:

```
int myMethod()
{
    if (cond)
        return anInt;
}
```

While **you** may know that `cond` is in fact always true, the compiler will **not** know that. It can only be sure about the result of a boolean expression if it is an expression which can be evaluated at compile time only.

Note that the vast majority of "code optimization" in Java is in fact done at run time (JIT: Just In Time).